# Is there a name for transformations that are rigid except for possible scaling?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, terminology

Is there a special name for the category of 3D transformation matrices that are rigid but then may have possibly non-uniform scaling / reflections included? I.e. transforms that can represent translations, rotations, scaling, and reflection; but not shear or other non-rigid transformations.

So, I guess, the name for all the matrices $T$ that can be represented as:

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}\begin{matrix}R\end{matrix} &\begin{matrix}t_x \\ t_y \\ t_z\end{matrix}\\\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix} &1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}s_x & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & s_y & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & s_z & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Where $R$ is some 3x3 orthogonal rotation matrix, $s_x\neq0$, $s_y\neq0$, $s_z\neq0$, and all the numbers are in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With uniform scaling, the transformation is called a *similarity*.

With non-uniform scaling, you can't avoid shear (think of a transformed diamond). I have never heard a specific term for the combination of an *isometry* and a non-uniform scaling (or conversely), which involves $5$ degrees of freedom. It makes more sense to consider a general *affinity* ($6$ DOF).